# Jframe buttons captions doesn't show

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working on a Java project in NetBeans. While in preview mode the captions of button and labels show. But when I run the project the captions disappear. What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Post your code. Its hard to guess the problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It has been solved. I did a Clean and Build Main Project. This deleted previous compiled files then recompiled the application.